# Installing libfprint and wrapping with Jlibfprint

Tags: java, c, api, fingerprint, libusb

I developed a fingerprint application which captures a finger and saved it to the file system. Now I am try to find the minutiae using the [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/)

I am also using [Jlibfprint](https://code.google.com/p/jlibfprint/) to wrap the app for java part. In the **ReadMe** file there is some instructions for calling a function

```
int fpi_img_compare_print_data(struct fp_print_data *enrolled_print,
    struct fp_print_data *new_print)
```

Instructions is:

```
 1.   To give the ability to compare two fingerprint data in Jlibfprint 
        you probabily need to patch the library in this way:
            - in libfprint find the file img.c and open it
            - find the function 
        int fpi_img_compare_print_data(struct fp_print_data *enrolled_print,
            struct fp_print_data *new_print)
            - add the attribute "API_EXPORTED" before the definition of the function:
        API_EXPORTED int fpi_img_compare_print_data(struct fp_print_data *enrolled_print,
            struct fp_print_data *new_print)

2. Open the jlibfprint_jni/Makefile file, search for the ADD_INCLUDE variable (near line 53),
    and specify the JDK include library and the path of the source files of the libfprint 
    you have just patched. Please take care to add also this subfolder: libfprint/nbis/include.
```

After completing all instructions when I try to use the function I get **function was out of scope error**.

I think I am doing something wrong here :

```
specify the path of the source files of the libfprint 
    you have just patched.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the inner interface, if you wanna use you must find the related object file in your build path, besides, you should add the function declaration in you .h file.